# Getting a entered variable to print - somethings amiss

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm a bit stuck getting the 'get' function to work correctly. The error occurs when I click the search button, it brings up the 'entry1' is not defined message in the shell. I've tried positioning the variable declaration in different positions, commenting it out and a variety of other tests but have come up stumps about what I'm doing wrong, I'm sure its fairly obvious but for a beginner I need a pointer.

The code should print numbers entered into the Shop Order field into the python shell and is a work in progress, hence does do too much.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
#import sys

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, rootWindow):

        #variable
        entry1 = StringVar()        
        var2 = 3
        var3 = 4 

        #item1
        self.label = ttk.Label(rootWindow, text="Shop Order:")
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=(E), padx=3, pady=3)

        self.entry1 = ttk.Entry(rootWindow, width=5)
        self.entry1.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=(W, E), padx=3, pady=3) 
        #item2
        self.label2 = ttk.Label(rootWindow, text="Quantity:")
        self.label2.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=(E), padx=3, pady=3)

        self.entry2 = ttk.Entry(rootWindow, width=5, textvariable=var2)
        self.entry2.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky=(W, E), padx=3, pady=3) 

        #item3
        self.label3 = ttk.Label(rootWindow, text="Description:")
        self.label3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=(E), padx=3, pady=3)

        self.entry3 = ttk.Entry(rootWindow, width=5, textvariable=var3)
        self.entry3.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=3, sticky=(W, E), padx=3, pady=3) 

        #output
        self.label4 = ttk.Label(rootWindow, text="Drawings:")
        self.label4.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=(N,E), padx=3, pady=3)

        #buttons

        self.button3 = ttk.Button(rootWindow, text="Exit", command=rootWindow.destroy)
        self.button3.grid(row=3, column=6, sticky=(N,W), padx=3, pady=3)

        self.text1 = Text(rootWindow, width=40, height=15, background="white")
        self.text1.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=4, padx=3, pady=3)

        def DoASearch():
            print (entry1.get())

        self.button1 = ttk.Button(rootWindow, text="Search", command=DoASearch)
        self.button1.grid(row=1, column=6, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)

        def clear_text():
            entry1.delete(0, 'end')

        self.button2 = ttk.Button(rootWindow, text="Reset", command=clear_text)
        self.button2.grid(row=2, column=6, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)

        def onExit(self):
            self.quit()

def main():
    global label   
    rootWindow = Tk()
    rootWindow.title("Some Random Title")
    rootWindow.geometry("500x325+600+300")
    gui = GUI(rootWindow)
    rootWindow.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: Something went wrong with your code formatting. Consult [Markdown help - Code and Preformatted Text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and did not get any `entry1 not defined` error, but I was able to recreate your issue that the `DoASearch` function was not printing into the shell what was entered in the Entry widget for Shop Order. I have been able to remedy that by first renaming your `StringVar()` variable to `entry10` instead of `entry1` since the program was confusing the Entry widget with the `StringVar()` as they were both assigned the same variable. Also, in your first Entry widget, you did not assign a `text variable` method to it, so it was not outputting what was entered into the `Shop Order:` field anyways. Finally, in your `clear_text` function, the exception `name 'entry1' is not defined` was thrown since `entry1` is an attribute of `self`, and thus just `entry1` cannot return what is entered into its assigned Entry widget. Instead `self.entry1` should be used to do that. Therefore, the following changes to your code should make it work as expected:

- Replace

  ```
  entry1 = StringVar()
  ```

  with

  ```
  entry10 = StringVar()
  ```
- Add `textvariable` to the Entry widget, like so:

  ```
  self.entry1 = ttk.Entry(rootWindow, width=5, textvariable = entry10)
  ```
- In the `DoASearch` function, replace

  ```
  print (entry1.get())
  ```

  with

  ```
  try:
      print(int(entry10.get()))
  except ValueError:
      messagebox.showwarning("Not a number", "That is not a number. Please enter a number")
  ```

  to make sure that it prints out a **number** if the user enters one in the Shop Order field, otherwise show a warning dialog if the user inputs anything other than a number.
- In the `clear_text` function, replace

  ```
  entry1.delete(0, 'end')
  ```

  with

  ```
  self.entry1.delete(0, 'end')
  ```

Following the above changes, when the user enters, for instance, 50 in the `Shop Order` entry widget, the output in the shell is `50`. Otherwise, if anything other than a number is entered, the following warning dialog is shown:

[image: Warning Dialog]

Also, when the user selects the `Reset` button now, the Shop Order entry box is cleared.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic R.Kap, thank you so much for your assistance and pointers. Works beautifully :)

Answer (score 2):

You have created a global variable named `entry1`, and you have an attribute named `self.entry1`. That isn't necessarily wrong, but it does make your code hard to understand. I'll explain why later.

You are trying to get the value of the variable like this:

```
def DoASearch():
    print (entry1.get())
```

However, you never assigned `entry1` to any widget, so the value will always just be whatever the default value is. Oddly, later on you attempt to use this same variable as if it were the entry widget when you do this:

```
def clear_text():
    entry1.delete(0, 'end')
```

That is why it is bad to have two different objects with very similar names. It's easy to confuse the two.

My advice is to remove the use of `StringVar` completely. You don't need it, and as you can see it can lead to confusion.

Instead, just directly get the value from the entry widget when you need it. Either by `self.entry1.get()` if calling from within the class, or `gui.entry1.get()` when called externally.

I recommend making `DoASearch` and `clear_text` methods of the class, so that you can use `self.entry1` everywhere.